# Populate Modal wih AJAX and WordPress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using AJAX along with WordPress to populate a modal window. The idea is the following:

- The user clicks on a custom post item.
- The `id` of this item is stored in a HTML attribute which then I send via AJAX to the server.
- Based on this attribute I execute a query to get the required info and populate the modal. The query is executed within a function which is located in the `functions.php` file. [See the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)).

The problem I have is how (if possible) can I call this function in another template of my theme. Basically I want to retrieve the data from this query and populate a specific template. But, I have tried to call it by using different simple methods (create global variables, return an array, etc.) and I cannot get the expected result. What I finally did is to retrieve the data from the server for this query and build the modal with JS by replacing the dynamic values. However, this is not a good solution and I'm trying to find a simpler and more efficient way of doing so.

Here's the function I'm using:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_product_categories_list', 'product_categories_list_info' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_product_categories_list', 'product_categories_list_info' );


function product_categories_list_info () {
    $term_id = $_POST['id'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_categories',
            'terms' => $term_id
             )
          )
        );

    $product_list = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $product_list -> have_posts() ) {
        while ( $product_list -> have_posts() ) {
            $product_list -> the_post();


            $product_title = get_the_title(); 
            $product_id = get_the_id();   

            $product_featured_image= the_field('product_featured_image', $product_id);

       }
    } 

   wp_reset_postdata();
 }
```

So, I want to get the values of the variables above and use them in another template.

Comment: Need to be a lot more specific about what the actual problems are. Using in different templates shouldn't be a problem if you include same script. Providing code will help and is expected

Comment: I updated the question with a code snippet.

Comment: There isn't any output from your function. WHat are you wanting to send ...html or json?

Comment: json. Note I used the json_encode() for sending an array of all the values as a response of the call. But I don't want to handle it client-side as explained.

Comment: Yes, what I said is that I have problems of doing so. I tried to set the variables as global: `$GLOBALS['product_featured_image']=..` and then output it in another template but it didn't work.

Comment: Where's the part that didn't work?

Comment: I just  want to print the `echo $GLOBALS['product_featured_image'];` in another template. The template is blank because I want to test it.

Comment: shouldn't need globals, can include the template file and buffer output

Comment: can you give me an example? The template needs to be part of another php file. I want only the values